# How to pass structures to a function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, argument-passing

I wrote a C code which is formed by these files: *main.c*, *kernel.c*. Here are the files:

*main.c*:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
} vect_xyz;

vect_xyz *coll_vcm1;

#include "kernel.c"
//==============================================================
int main(void){

int Np=10, i;   
float xx = 1;
coll_vcm1=(vect_xyz*)malloc(Np*sizeof(vect_xyz));

for(i=0;i<Np;i++){
  coll_vcm1[i].x = xx;
  coll_vcm1[i].y = 2*xx;
  coll_vcm1[i].z = 3*xx;
  xx = xx + 1;
}

for(i=0;i<Np;i++){
  collisione(coll_vcm1[i].x,i);
}

return 0;
}
```

*kernel.c*

```
void collisione(vect_xyz *coll_vcm1,int i){ 
  printf("coll_vcm1[%d].x=%f\n",i,coll_vcm1[i].x);
}
```

Here is the make file:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
OBJS = main.o 

all: eseguibile

eseguibile: $(OBJS)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o eseguibile -lm

main.o: main.c kernel.c
   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.c

clean:
  rm -rf *.o eseguibile
```

(watch out for the tabs). When I run it by typing *make* I get this error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:30:7: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘collisione’
   collisione(coll_vcm1[i].x,i);
   ^
In file included from main.c:14:0:
kernel.c:1:6: note: expected ‘struct vect_xyz *’ but argument is of type ‘float’
void collisione(vect_xyz *coll_vcm1,int i){ 
  ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Of course the mistake occurs when I call the function *collisione()* but I don't understand why. The other thing that I suppose to be wrong is in the *kernel.c* file; as a matter of fact I believe that writing `vect_xyz *coll_vcm1` is wrong because I am not specifying the index *i*.

So here is my question:
- What should I write in the *kernel.c* file in order to print the values of structure everytime in the for loop?

PS: I want to keep the loop

```
for(i=0;i<Np;i++){
  collisione(coll_vcm1[i].x,i);
}
```

outside of the *kernel.c* file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this

```
collisione(coll_vcm1[i].x,i);
```

to

```
collisione(coll_vcm1, i);
```

you where passing the `x` field at position `i` in the array, instead of the pointer to the array `coll_vcm1`

Also, note that [casting the return value from `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495) makes you among other things, repeat yourself.

```
coll_vcm1=(vect_xyz*)malloc(Np*sizeof(vect_xyz));
```

could just be

```
coll_vcm1 = malloc(Np * sizeof(vect_xyz));
```

and what you actually should do, is check the return value, on error `malloc()` returns `NULL`, so

```
coll_vcm1 = malloc(Np * sizeof(vect_xyz));
if (coll_vcm1 == NULL)
    tragedy_cannotAllocateMemory_DoNot_Continue();
```

and finally take your time to format your code, so others and you can read it and understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The error message speaks for itself, isn't it?

> incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘collisione’
>
> expected ‘struct vect_xyz *’ but argument is of type ‘float’

Your function prototype is

```
void collisione(vect_xyz *coll_vcm1,int i)
```

and you're calling this function like

```
collisione(coll_vcm1[i].x,i);
```

where, the first supplied argument `coll_vcm1[i].x` is of type `float`. You need to change that to

```
collisione(coll_vcm1, i);
```

so that the first argument is of type `vect_xyz *`.

Note: Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.